# Devise + OmniAuth - How to capture a FB Connect on registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm building a registration flow that allows a user to FB Connect to pre-populate the registration form. I'm also then capturing fb_uuid and fb_access_token.

When the user submits the registration form that is submitted as follows:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jul 11 17:44:40 -0700 2011
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create my account", "fb_access_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXX", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXX", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "lname"=>"NNNNNN", "fname"=>"BBBBBB", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"dadad@google.com"}, "fb_uuid"=>"50123190"}
```

**notice the fb_access_token, fb_uuid**

In the Registration#Create, how can I capture those values and populate the Authentications table? Do I have to override devise?

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Although you may not need this right now, here's a blog post that you can use to solver your problem:

[Devise on rails: Prepopulating form data](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/06/devise-on-rails-prepopulating-form-data.html)

You can use the method described there to capture and process the data you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the koala gem to pull those fb parameters from the facebook cookie after the user does a FB_Connect.  Take a look at this:
https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails

I'm curious on why you aren't creating the user right after the FB_Connect which is the more common and intuitive user experience, as opposed to just prepoulating the registration form.
Like this:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: thanks but I want to use FB to prepopulate the form, then have the user enter a password. This is the same flow used on sites like Quora...

Comment: Thanks for the link to Koala, but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking about how you can capture fb params (access_token and uid) after the user is redirected back from a FB Connect. So are you wondering about how to add those params to your Devise user without customizing devise?